# sent params from angularJs to php symfony2 api

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, symfony

I want to call a php method using angular service. I do this :

```
 save:function(){
              var req = {
                  method: "GET",
                  url: "/api/save/",
                  data: {
                      nom:"nom"
                  }
              }
              var deferred = $q.defer();
              $http(req).
                  success(function(result) {
                      console.log(req);
                      deferred.resolve(result);
                  })
```

and in my php controller :

```
 public function savePersonnelAction(Request $httpRequest){

        $content= $httpRequest->query->get('data');
 return $this->render('clientBundle:Default:index.html.twig',array('content'=>$content));
}
```

But I have an empty object as a result.

Can someone help me to resolve this problem please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you only want to send some data in a query string?

For a GET request, you should use `params`, not `data` attribute.

`data` is used for a POST request content.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
 $content= $httpRequest->query->get('nom');
```

Cheers

Comment: I have `null`as result

Comment: `null` where? In your view?

Comment: Yes in the view. But I see the result in the debbuger

Comment: So, your angular service seems to be the suspect one.

Comment: As Mateusz said you have to use `params` for get request: `... params: { nom:"nom" ... }`